# How to make colored swatches inside text?

Tags: color

The following is an image of a sub-section of the documentation of the package `xcolor`.

[image: Inline color swatch]

How to insert such a color swatch within text? I need it to explain the functionality of different parts of a schematic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could inspect the original source code for the [`xcolor` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.dtx).

It uses a `\colorbox` that has a tight (`\fboxsep` is set to `\z@` = 0pt) `\fbox` around it.
The dimension of the colored box is taken from the string “XX”. The macro `\phantom` expands to a box with the dimension of its argument.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\def\testclr#1#{\@testclr{#1}}
\def\@testclr#1#2{{\fboxsep\z@\fbox{\colorbox#1{#2}{\phantom{XX}}}}}
\newcommand*\Color[1]{\textsl{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item How does a mixture of 40\% \Color{green} and 60\% \Color{yellow} look like?\\
(Answer: 40\% \testclr{green} $+$ 60\% \testclr{yellow} $=$ \testclr{green!40!yellow}, e.g., \verb|\color{green!40!yellow}|)
\item And how does its complementary color look like?\\
(Answer: \testclr{-green!40!yellow}, accessible via \verb|\color{-green!40!yellow}|)
\item Now I want to mix three parts of the last color with two parts of its complement and one part of \Color{red}.
How does that look?\\
(Answer: $3\times$ \testclr{-green!40!yellow} $+ 2\times$ \testclr{green!40!yellow} $+ 1\times$ \testclr{red} $=$ \testclr{rgb:-green!40!yellow,3;green!40!yellow,2;red,1}, the last color being accessible via \verb|\color{rgb:-green!40!yellow,3;green!40!yellow,2;red,1}|)
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

I think the other answer is the way to go, but just in case you'd like to do it with `tikz`, here's an option

[image: screenshot]

This gives you access to all of the fun things that `tikz` can do such as `rounded corners` and `decorated paths` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\swatch}[1]{\tikz[baseline=-0.6ex] \node[fill=#1,shape=rectangle,draw=black,thick,minimum width=5mm,rounded corners=2pt](){};}

\begin{document}
Answer: 40\% \swatch{green}+60\% \swatch{yellow}=\swatch{green!40!yellow}
\end{document}
```